# Display img elements in vertical stack next to other img?

Tags: css, image, alignment, css-float

I'm trying to display a group of img elements like this:

[image]

I tried using float: left on IMG 1 and float: right on the other IMGs but they don't line up vertically. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to **have two child `divs` in the container `div`**. One should be `img1` and the other should **contain the other three**, which should also have `display: block;` to work properly (*img2, img3 and img 4*).

- Put `float: left;` on `img1` and `float: right` on the `container` of the three smaller ones.
- To be on the safe side, put again on both `img1` and the new `container`: `vertical-align: middle`.
- If the containers also have fixed dimensions it'll be even easier.

**Image**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. I never thought of that but I think it should work.

Comment: Your welcome. It'll work. It's easier trying to align two elements than five.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox should work with this.

Firstly, set `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on parent container.

Secondly, set `display: flex` then `flex-direction: column` on the right container.

The images will be vertical aligned.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.right img {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
  </div>
</div>
```